# Перебрать все блоки на странице с одинаковыми классами и обрезать в них содержимое

Tags: javascript

На странице существует несколько блоков с одинаковыми классами.
Надо взять все эти блоки и обрезать в каждом из них содержимое до 14 символов, а после положить обратно уже с обрезанным содержимым.

Собственно, блоки выглядят следующим образом, только на самом сайте их гораздо больше:

```
<span id="btc-price" class="btc-price cryptocurrency-price">19461.26972173</span>
<span id="eth-price" class="eth-price cryptocurrency-price">1009.1328179263</span>
<span id="usdt-price" class="usdt-price cryptocurrency-price">0.99884622030755</span>
<span id="usdc-price" class="usdc-price cryptocurrency-price">1.0003357800278</span>
```

Скрипт, который их должен изменять:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    let cryptoPrice = document.querySelector(".cryptocurrency-price");
    for (let i = 0; i < cryptoPrice.length; i++) {
            let priceInner = cryptoPrice.innerHTML;
            let length = 14;
            let trimmedString = priceInner.substring(0,length);
            console.log(trimmedString);
    }
});
</script>
```

Пока что я не делал записи в блоки получившегося содержимого, просто пытался вывести результат в консоль, но там пустота.

Никаких ошибок тоже нет. Частями код работает, а всё вместе почему-то нет.

Comment: Но таким способом получится, что чем больше целая часть числа, тем меньше знаков после запятой. Есть математический метод .tofixed(14), который оставляет определенное количество знаков после запятой.

Comment: @Опан это не математический метод, а скорее обезьяний, т.к. там число режется в тупую, не проводя никаких арифметических операций.

Comment: Увы, не в тупую, операция проводится. Число округляется до ближайшего значения с указанным количеством цифр после запятой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.cryptocurrency-price');

blocks.forEach(item => {
  item.textContent = item.textContent.slice(0, 13);
})
```

```css
.cryptocurrency-price {
display: block;
}
```

```html
  <span id="btc-price" class="btc-price cryptocurrency-price">19461.26972173</span>
  <span id="eth-price" class="eth-price cryptocurrency-price">1009.1328179263</span>
  <span id="usdt-price" class="usdt-price cryptocurrency-price">0.99884622030755</span>
  <span id="usdc-price" class="usdc-price cryptocurrency-price">1.0003357800278</span>
```

Comment: Это как раз то, что нужно!
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Для каждого числа сохраняется 14 числен после запятой:

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.cryptocurrency-price');

blocks.forEach(e => {
  e.innerText = (+e.innerText).toFixed(14)
})
```

```css
.cryptocurrency-price {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<span id="btc-price" class="btc-price cryptocurrency-price">19461.26972173</span>
<span id="eth-price" class="eth-price cryptocurrency-price">1009.1328179263</span>
<span id="usdt-price" class="usdt-price cryptocurrency-price">0.99884622030755</span>
<span id="usdc-price" class="usdc-price cryptocurrency-price">1.0003357800278</span>
```

Просто у этого метода есть проблема, если длина числа после запятой меньше чем то число которые имеется, то тогда оно заменяется на какое-нибудь другое, если вам это не нужно то тогда вот ещё один вариант, без этой проблемы:

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.cryptocurrency-price');

blocks.forEach(e => {
  if(e.innerText.split('.')[1].length > 14) e.innerText = (+e.innerText).toFixed(14)
})
```

```css
.cryptocurrency-price {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<span id="btc-price" class="btc-price cryptocurrency-price">19461.26972173</span>
<span id="eth-price" class="eth-price cryptocurrency-price">1009.1328179263</span>
<span id="usdt-price" class="usdt-price cryptocurrency-price">0.99884622030755</span>
<span id="usdc-price" class="usdc-price cryptocurrency-price">1.0003357800278</span>
```

Comment: Нет, смысл был в том, чтобы просто оставить 14 символов, не после запятой, а в целом

Comment: @NewUserror, но разве в криптовалютах не важна точность цены?

Comment: Тут как посмотреть)
Зависит от задачи.
Но спасибо за ответ!